# Emacs - Undefine Prefix Key

Tags: emacs, elisp

I somehow managed to define the 'M' (capital em) key as a prefix key in sqlplus-mode which is preventing me from typing an M.

How can I unset this prefix key in this mode?

Comment: You probably forgot the backslash in `(define-key keymap "\M-?" #'function)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short term fix:

```
M-x local-set-key M self-insert-command
```

Long term fix, find the spot in your .emacs file which defines it a ssuch.  @tripleee's comment does sound like a likely candidate for what went wrong.

Comment: How do I type the M though? Whenever I try it uses the prefix!

Comment: Ah, the fix is not to run it interactively

Comment: @JustinValentini: You can also always enter a literal character by preceding it with `C-q` for "quote".

Comment: @Jon, I tried that but when call interactively it treats the C-q as the key to set

Comment: I think you can try M-x eval-expression RET (local-set-key "M" 'self-insert-command) RET. The M you type there you must probably prefix with C-q.