# eMacs: Alphabet (`E`) key-binding was accidentally disabled/overwritten

Tags: emacs

As of now, I'm no longer able to type `E` (i.e., ASCII character 69) in emacs which is pretty devastating considering I'm in the middle of a Haskell exercise on the `Either` type constructor.

The only major change I've made today was installing the w3m (web browser) package though I can't identify any shortcuts mapped to "S-e".  I tried `(global-unset-key "S-e")` which didn't work (I later realized that this simply undid the current key-binding but didn't actually set a new one).

Any emac gurus with suggestions for a quick code addition to my .emacs file which would (i) give me back "E" (i.e., `Shift` + `e`) while (ii) not requiring me to actually type the character 'E' as part of the emacs Lisp (e.g., using the ascii character)?

Am running emacs 24, Xubuntu 14 (virtualbox).

Comment: What does `C-h k E` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(global-set-key "E" 'self-insert-command)
```

could get you closer to a working state again. To get a capital "E", type e and run `M-x upcase-region` on it.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck with either (i) `(global-set-key "E" 'self-insert-command)` (I reloaded my .emacs file but no change) or (ii) `C-q 105 RET` (I get a message that says `No cross reference here`)

Comment: @DipakC: You could try evaluating that line directly with `M-:` incase whatever overrides it is called after your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

First you can ask question about emacs in `http://emacs.stackexchange.com/` ,  others try type `C-h c` then `S-e` to inspect which command has been invoked

Comment: Didn't know about the emacs-specific forum - will direct my questions there in the future, thanks.  I did try `C-h k S-e`, which results in the following appearing in my mini-buffer: `E-` (there was a hyphen following the `E`).  After pressing `RET`, the following message flashes in my mini-buffer `E RET is undefined`.  It's odd since a keystroke after invoking `C-h k` will typically either take me to the summary page for the pressed key(s) or will flashe a `[..] is undefined` message in the mini-buffer.

Comment: Seems like you make `S-e` a prefix key binding, you can refer the similar question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820058/emacs-undefine-prefix-key`